# A Dictionary for English used by poets like Chaucer

Tags: middle-english

I am trying to read Canterbury tales by Chaucer. Now, I am not a native English speaker. So, the trouble I had in reading it goes like this. Take the beginning,

"Whan that Aprille with his shoures soote, 
The droghte of March hath perced to the roote "

Now some of those words are obvious, but it took me considerable googling to get the meaning of 'shoures'.

So, my question is, Is there any dictionary that specialises on this kind of words and spelling?

Comment: Hi, Anand, welcome to EL&U! Questions requesting references are generally a better fit on our Meta site; I think you'll find some great resources for your project in [this answer](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2574/177853) (scroll down for the section on Historical and dialectical dictionaries). Good luck with your Chaucer exploration!

Comment: Many editions include notes. See e.g. http://www.librarius.com/canttran/gptrfs.htm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Middle English Compendium at the University of Michigan: https://quod.lib.umich.edu/m/middle-english-dictionary/dictionary